# List of products from the given category

Tags: django, django-views

I'm just getting started and I have a problem. I want to get in
SlugView a list of all products in the given category ('slug').

models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    category_name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True)

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    description = models.TextField()
    price = models.FloatField()
    vat = models.FloatField(choices=VAT)
    stock = models.IntegerField()
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)

    @property
    def name(self):
        return "Nazwa: {}, cena: {}".format(self.name, self.price)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

views.py

```
class SlugView(View):
    def get(self, request, slug):
        category = Category.objects.filter(slug=slug)
        return render(request,'exercises/slug.html', {'products': products})
```

urls.py

```
 re_path(r'categories/(?P<slug>\w+)', SlugView.as_view(), name = "slug")
```

Bug list:
'''
    Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
    Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
    [05/Feb/2020 09:46:37] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 965
    [05/Feb/2020 09:46:42] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 965
    [05/Feb/2020 09:46:45] "GET /categories HTTP/1.1" 200 997
    Internal Server Error: /categories/1234D
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/marekk/Pulpit/kurs/Django_cwicz/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 828, in _resolve_lookup
        current = current[bit]
    TypeError: 'Product' object is not subscriptable

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/marekk/Pulpit/kurs/Django_cwicz/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/marekk/Pulpit/kurs/Django_cwicz/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/marekk/Pulpit/kurs/Django_cwicz/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/marekk/Pulpit/kurs/Django_cwicz/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/marekk/Pulpit/kurs/Django_cwicz/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 97, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/marekk/Pulpit/kurs/django-za2/WAR_PYT_W_11_Zaawansowane_Django/3_Django/coderslab/exercises/views.py", line 30, in get
        return render(request,'exercises/slug.html', {'products': products})
      File "/home/marekk/Pulpit/kurs/Django_cwicz/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 19, in render
        content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
      File "/home/marekk/Pulpit/kurs/Django_cwicz/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
        return template.render(context, request)
      File "/home/marekk/Pulpit/kurs/Django_cwicz/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 61, in render
        return self.template.render(context)
      File "/home/marekk/Pulpit/kurs/Django_cwicz/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 171, in render
        return self._render(context)
      File "/home/marekk/Pulpit/kurs/Django_cwicz/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 163, in _render
        return self.nodelist.render(context)
      File "/home/marekk/Pulpit/kurs/Django_cwicz/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
        bit = node.render_annotated(context)
      File "/home/marekk/Pulpit/kurs/Django_cwicz/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
        return self.render(context)
      File "/home/marekk/Pulpit/kurs/Django_cwicz/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
        return compiled_parent._render(context)
      File "/home/marekk/Pulpit/kurs/Django_cwicz/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 163, in _render
        return self.nodelist.render(context)
      File "/home/marekk/Pulpit/kurs/Django_cwicz/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
        bit = node.render_annotated(context)
      File "/home/marekk/Pulpit/kurs/Django_cwicz/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
        return self.render(context)
      File "/home/marekk/Pulpit/kurs/Django_cwicz/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
        result = block.nodelist.render(context)
      File "/home/marekk/Pulpit/kurs/Django_cwicz/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
        bit = node.render_annotated(context)
      File "/home/marekk/Pulpit/kurs/Django_cwicz/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
        return self.render(context)
      File "/home/marekk/Pulpit/kurs/Django_cwicz/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
        result = block.nodelist.render(context)
      File "/home/marekk/Pulpit/kurs/Django_cwicz/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
        bit = node.render_annotated(context)
      File "/home/marekk/Pulpit/kurs/Django_cwicz/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
        return self.render(context)
      File "/home/marekk/Pulpit/kurs/Django_cwicz/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 209, in render
        nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))
      File "/home/marekk/Pulpit/kurs/Django_cwicz/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
        return self.render(context)
      File "/home/marekk/Pulpit/kurs/Django_cwicz/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
        result = block.nodelist.render(context)
      File "/home/marekk/Pulpit/kurs/Django_cwicz/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
        bit = node.render_annotated(context)
      File "/home/marekk/Pulpit/kurs/Django_cwicz/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
        return self.render(context)
      File "/home/marekk/Pulpit/kurs/Django_cwicz/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 986, in render
        output = self.filter_expression.resolve(context)
      File "/home/marekk/Pulpit/kurs/Django_cwicz/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 670, in resolve
        obj = self.var.resolve(context)
      File "/home/marekk/Pulpit/kurs/Django_cwicz/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 795, in resolve
        value = self._resolve_lookup(context)
      File "/home/marekk/Pulpit/kurs/Django_cwicz/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 836, in _resolve_lookup
        current = getattr(current, bit)
      File "/home/marekk/Pulpit/kurs/django-za2/WAR_PYT_W_11_Zaawansowane_Django/3_Django/coderslab/exercises/models.py", line 88, in name
        return "Nazwa: {}, cena: {}".format(self.name, self.price)
      File "/home/marekk/Pulpit/kurs/django-za2/WAR_PYT_W_11_Zaawansowane_Django/3_Django/coderslab/exercises/models.py", line 88, in name
        return "Nazwa: {}, cena: {}".format(self.name, self.price)
      File "/home/marekk/Pulpit/kurs/django-za2/WAR_PYT_W_11_Zaawansowane_Django/3_Django/coderslab/exercises/models.py", line 88, in name
        return "Nazwa: {}, cena: {}".format(self.name, self.price)
      [Previous line repeated 449 more times]
    RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
    [05/Feb/2020 09:46:49] "GET /categories/1234D HTTP/1.1" 500 1694912
```

'''

Here you are templates.

template "slug.html"
'''

```
{% extends 'exercises/base.html' %}

{% block page_title %}
            <h1>Sklep internetowy OLABOGA.</h1>
      {% endblock %}

{% block content_title %}<h2>Produkty w kategorii:</h2>
 {% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <ul>
        {% for product in products %}
            {% block element %}
                <li><a href='/{% block link %}product{% endblock %}/
                    {{ product.name }}'>{{ product.name }}</a></li>
            {% endblock %}
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endblock %}
```

'''

template "base.html"
'''

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    {% block logo %}
        <img src="{% static 'images/logo.png' %}" alt="Tu powinno być logo" >
    {% endblock %}
   {% block page_content %}
      {% block page_title %}
            <h1>Szkoła podstawowa nr 1 im. Chucka Norrisa.</h1>
      {% endblock %}
       {% block content_title %}
                <h2>Klasy:</h2>
       {% endblock %}
       {% block content %}
                <ul>
                    {% for object in objects %}
                        {% block element %}
                            <li><a href='/{% block link %}class{% endblock %}/{}'>{}</a></li>
                        {% endblock %}
                    {% endfor %}
                </ul>
       {% endblock %}
       {% block additional %}
       {% endblock %}
   {% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

'''

Problem is in this part of code, but I don't know why:

```
@property
def name(self):
    return "Nazwa: {}, cena: {}".format(self.name, self.price)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

in this row (this is line 88 in models.py)

return "Nazwa: {}, cena: {}".format(self.name, self.price)

error messages:

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/categories/1234C
Django Version:     3.0
Exception Type:     RecursionError
Exception Value:

maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

Exception Location:     /home/marekk/Pulpit/kurs/django-za2/WAR_PYT_W_11_Zaawansowane_Django/3_Django/coderslab/exercises/models.py in name, line 88

to views.py I added:

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()
@register.filter
def multiply(value, arg):
    return value * arg
```

to template I added:

```
{{ product.price|multiply:product.vat }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your goal to get `Products` through `Category` you can filter on M2M related records:

```
products = Product.objects.filter(categories__slug=slug)
return render(request,'exercises/slug.html', {'products': products})
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207389/discussion-on-answer-by-charnel-list-of-products-from-the-given-category).

Answer (score 1):

First get the category using the `get()` method instead of `filter()` method since *get* returns the single object whereas *filter* returns the queryset.Then you can get the related products to the category like this.

```
 class CategoryView(View):
    def get(self, request, slug):
        category = Category.objects.get(slug=slug)
        products = category.product_set.all()
        return render(request,'exercises/slug.html', {'products': products})
```

And here I changed your class name to `CategoryView` instead of `SlugView` for the better understanding.

Comment: '''class CategoryView(View):
    def get(self, request, slug):
        category = Category.objects.get(slug=slug)
        products = category.product_set.all()
        return render(request,'exercises/slug.html', {'products': products})'''

Comment: I have error :'Product' object is not subscriptable